# Solution to use instead of $global variable?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, caching, global-variables

I have a cached object that takes quite some time to calculate (~ 30 seconds). I recalculate this object every 24 hours, and if that happens, sometimes users are experiencing time outs if they happen to be here at the same time. The object I'm caching currently works like this:

```
  def matrix    
    Rails.cache.fetch(["matrix"], expires_in: 24.hours) do
      # Math
    end
  end
```

What I would like to do, is attach a version to this. That way I can calculate a new "matrix" in the background with a different method...

```
  def rewrite_matrix
    new_version = DateTime.now.to_s

    Rails.cache.fetch(["matrix", new_version], expires_in: 24.hours) do
      # Math
    end

    $matrix_version = new_version # This feels like a faux pas.
  end
```

and then change my matrix method to something like...

```
 def matrix
    $matrix_version ||= DateTime.now.to_s

    Rails.cache.fetch(["matrix", $matrix_version], expires_in: 24.hours) do
      # Math
    end
  end
```

I've been reading about global variables in Ruby/Rails, and everything says they shouldn't be touched? Would this $matrix_version variable be available in other processes and to other users? Anyway, I was hoping for an idea on how to workaround or create a new cache version in the background and then starting to use it when it only when it is finished calculating and stored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first idea that comes to mind is just doing the calculation first:

```
def matrix    
  Rails.cache.fetch('matrix') do
    calculate_matrix
  end
end

def rewrite_matrix
  new_version = calculate_matrix

  Rails.cache.delete('matrix')
  Rails.cache.fetch('matrix') do
    new_version
  end

end

def calculate_matrix
  #Math
end
```

If you call `rewrite_matrix` every 24 hours (in a separate process), it should do the work first and THEN update the cache, which will remain available to the users while it's working.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend not expiring the cache, if it takes 24 hours. Instead, just replace it when you have a new version ready.

```
class YourModel
  def matrix    
    Rails.cache.fetch(["matrix"]) do
      math
    end
  end

  def self.recalculate_matrix
    Rails.cache.set(["matrix"]) do
      math
    end
  end
end
```

Then, maybe using the [whenever gem](https://github.com/javan/whenever):

```
every 1.day, :at => '4:30 am' do
  runner "MyModel.recalculate_matrix"
end
```